# Android Data Binding SetSupportActionBar

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

Hi I wonder if there is an xml tag for this function using Android Data Binding Library or how to achieve this without findViewById() method

Thank You

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html
there are other methods in link below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access the instance of the toolbar [using views by id](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#views_with_ids) function

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

then on your `onCreate()` method do the following

```
ActivityGalleryBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
    .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_gallery);
binding.setViewModel(new GalleryModel(this));
//set it like this
setSupportActionBar(binding.<location>.<of>.<your>.toolbar);
```

if your toolbar is inside other xml component (referenced with `<include/>`) you still can access it as long as you provide and `@id` to the `<include/>`

Comment: what if toolbar is included in the include layout? Or if there is multiple view in included layout?

Comment: i have used `DataBinding` in custom toolbar and using `<include>` , the toolbar is used in `activity_main.xml`, but i have not used `DataBinding` in `activity_main.xml`, then how to get `toolbarBinding(custom toolbar)` in mainActivity.

Comment: How about `binding.root.toolbar` if it is inside `<include>` ?

Answer (score 1):

**Make** project in **Android Studio** then you can use below code for accessing toolbar:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    >
  <data>
    <variable
        type="com.example.viewModel"
        name="viewModel"
        />
  </data>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
      app:title="@{viewModel.title}"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: can you share viewmodel code where you change the title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way. This Answered for me After many searches.

1. use `id` for your include, example my toolbar id is `tb` and include `id` is `mtoolbar`
2. now use `setSupportActionBar(mainBinding.mtoolbar.tb);`